# Menu fields and OutlinedTextField not rendering

Tags: android, kotlin

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.littlelemon

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.Image
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxHeight
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.material.Button
import androidx.compose.material.OutlinedTextField
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.livedata.observeAsState
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.res.painterResource
import androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextAlign
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.lifecycle.lifecycleScope
import androidx.room.Room
import com.example.littlelemon.ui.theme.LittleLemonTheme
import io.ktor.client.HttpClient
import io.ktor.client.call.body
import io.ktor.client.engine.android.Android
import io.ktor.client.plugins.contentnegotiation.ContentNegotiation
import io.ktor.client.request.get
import io.ktor.http.ContentType
import io.ktor.serialization.kotlinx.json.json
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private val httpClient = HttpClient(Android) { 
        install(ContentNegotiation) {
            json(contentType = ContentType("text", "plain"))
        }
    }
    private val database by lazy {
        Room.databaseBuilder(applicationContext, AppDatabase::class.java, "database").build()
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            LittleLemonTheme {
                val databaseMenuItems bydatabase.menuItemDao().getAll().observeAsState(emptyList())
    
                var orderMenuItems by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    
                var searchPhrase by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(16.dp)
                ) {
                    Image(
                        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.logo),
                        contentDescription = "logo",
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(50.dp)
                    )
                    Button(onClick = { orderMenuItems = true }) {
                        Text("Tap To Order By Name")
                    }
    
                    OutlinedTextField(
                        value = searchPhrase,
                        onValueChange = { newSearchPhrase -> searchPhrase = newSearchPhrase },
                        Modifier.padding(50.dp),
                    )
    
                    var menuItems = if (orderMenuItems) {
                        databaseMenuItems.sortedBy { it.title }
                    } else {
                        databaseMenuItems
                    }
                    MenuItemsList(menuItems)
    
                    MenuItemsList(items = databaseMenuItems)
                }
            }
        }
    
        lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            if (database.menuItemDao().isEmpty()) {
                val fullMenu = fetchMenu()
                saveMenuToDatabase(fullMenu)
            }
        }
    }
    
    private suspend fun fetchMenu(): List<MenuItemNetwork> {
        var menuitems = httpClient.get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Meta-Mobile-Developer-PC/Working-With-Data-API/main/littleLemonSimpleMenu.json").body<MenuNetwork>()
        return menuitems.menuItems
    }
    
    private fun saveMenuToDatabase(menuItemsNetwork: List<MenuItemNetwork>) {
        val menuItemsRoom = menuItemsNetwork.map { it.toMenuItemRoom() }
        database.menuItemDao().insertAll(*menuItemsRoom.toTypedArray())
    }
}
```

```
@Composable
private fun MenuItemsList(items: List<MenuItemRoom>) {
    LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight().padding(top = 20.dp)) {
        items(items = items, itemContent = { menuItem ->
            Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) { 
                Text(menuItem.title)
                Text(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f).padding(5.dp),textAlign = TextAlign.Right,text = "%.2f".format(menuItem.price))
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Database.kt

```
package com.example.littlelemon

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.room.Dao
import androidx.room.Database
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.Insert
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey
import androidx.room.Query
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase

@Entity
data class MenuItemRoom(
    @PrimaryKey 
    val id: Int,
    val title: String,
    val price: Double
)

@Dao
interface MenuItemDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM MenuItemRoom")
    fun getAll(): LiveData<List<MenuItemRoom>>

    @Insert
    fun insertAll(vararg menuItems: MenuItemRoom)
    
    @Query("SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MenuItemRoom) == 0")
    fun isEmpty(): Boolean    
}

@Database(entities = [MenuItemRoom::class], version = 1)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun menuItemDao(): MenuItemDao
}
```

Network.kt

```
package com.example.littlelemon

import kotlinx.serialization.SerialName
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable


@Serializable
data class MenuNetwork(
    @SerialName("menu")
    val menuItems: List<MenuItemNetwork>
)

@Serializable
data class MenuItemNetwork(
    @SerialName("id")
    val id: Int,
    @SerialName("title")
    val title: String,
    @SerialName("price")
    val price: Double,
) {
    fun toMenuItemRoom() = MenuItemRoom(id, title, price)
}
```

Comment: sorry for poor formatting i don't know nothing about stack overflow right  now